# QTableView shows no data, when associated model has got data

Tags: qt, sqlite

I am playing with Qt (I am a beginner), and trying to show a table's data in a QTableView.
So far I have this:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

QSqlDatabase db;
db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("test.db");

if (db.open())
    qDebug() << "success";
else
    qDebug() << "failed";
QSqlTableModel model;
model.setTable("names");
model.select();
qDebug() << model.rowCount();

ui->tableView->setModel(&model);
```

The problem is that, the model does get the data(2 rows), but the QTableView does now show it.

Any clues what is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your code it could be your `model` object is going out of scope. Make these few changes, hopefully they will get your issue corrected.

```
ui->setupUi( this );

// Setup db
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("test.db");

if( db.open() )
    qDebug() << "success";
else
    qDebug() << "failed";

// Initialize your model with the database.
QSqlTableModel* model = new QSqlTableModel( this, db );

// Let the QTableView take ownership of the model.
ui->tableView->setModel( model );

// Add the rest of your code here.
model->setTable( "names" );
model->select();
qDebug() << model->rowCount();
```